# Combining JPEG files into an MP4

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I have a collection of 100-200 JPEG images, and I want to combine them and create an MP4 file with H.264 encoding, on Windows Phone 8.

[I know Winodws Phone 8 supports H.264](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_VideoSupport)

I need to know:

- is there a way of combining JPEG files into an MP4 on WP8?
- if yes, can it be done without third-parties? If it can be done only with third parties, please specify which.

Any info is more than welcomed.